# Only FF shows no image, other browsers works well

Tags: firefox, iis

Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE work fine.
But Firefox fails to load images.

This site is running on `Windows Server 2003` and `IIS6`. And you have to consider that the image folder is a shared folder.
I have no idea why it’s not shown via Firefox only.

If someone has faced similar problems, please share your solutions with me.
FYI, I checked the option; and `Tools > Options > Content tab > Load images automatically` is checked.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do your <img> tags look like?

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky, it's like this; `<IMG ... src="\img\view\s/10\03\10\YMA_793.jpg" width=62 height=50>`. Maybe I should make '\' to '/' ..?

Comment: If I have to replace `\` to `/`, please show me how to replace `\` and '/' in asp function. It makes an error in asp function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pur URIs in your `src` attribute.  URIs always use `/` as a path separator.

No idea how to fix this in ASP; check your manual?